# Temporarily flip website upside down using JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

As a December 28th joke, I would like to temporarily flip my webpage upside down with this code:

```
body {
transform:rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

and I want to put this code javascript for time:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ },3000);
```

How I can adapt the css code?

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Comment: More like 'Java' is to 'Javascript' as 'Chocolate Chip' is to 'Chocolate Chip Cookie'.

Comment: Huh? The carpet one works lol, not the chocolate chip cookie.

Comment: What kinds of jokes do you do on the other days of the year?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a class, add the class to the body to perform the transform then remove it after

```
body.transform {
  transform:rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

```
document.body.className = 'transform';
setTimeout(function(){ document.body.className = ''; },3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function flip() {    
Array.prototype.slice.call(  document.querySelectorAll(    'div,p,span,img,a,body')).map(function(tag){tag.style['transform'] = 'rotate(' + 180 +'deg)';});
}
function unflip() {    
Array.prototype.slice.call(  document.querySelectorAll(    'div,p,span,img,a,body')).map(function(tag){tag.style['transform'] = 'rotate(' + 0 +'deg)';});
}
```

is a way to flip everything on screen then simply

```
flip()
```

then to unflip do

```
unflip()
```